# 301 Redirect with GatsbyJS on Heroku

Tags: redirect, heroku, routes, seo, gatsby

I just finished working on an app using `GatsbyJS`. I'm hosting my web application on `heroku`. I have a custom domain reversed through `heroku` with SSL support. Now I'm able to visit the following domains:

```
http://myapp.com
https://myapp.com
http://www.myapp.com
https://www.myapp.com
```

Normally you want to have 301 redirects from `www` to `non-www` and from `http://` to `https://`. Since the heroku router does not have the ability to force SSL, they want you to handle the redirects on the application level.

I did not found any solutions for SEO optimized 301 redirects within `GatsbyJS`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Heroku but if 301 redirect is not possible just ensure your pages have `<link rel="canonical" href="" />` tags. That is a way to hint the search engines the URL you want to be indexed. Additionally you may redirect to https:// on the client using the `onClientEntry` API.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your suggestion. As I will be posting data from the app to other services, I need to ensure its not possible to submit via http. Also no redirects from www to non-www are very bad for SEO. Indeed the canonical link will help you to not get indexed for "duplicate content". I was not fully aware of all the browser-api from gatsby. I will try the `onClientEntry`. Still I am not sure, that it will fit my needs. I hopefully will be able to transform the location, but I also need to make it as a 301 response

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to get it to run on heroku. Since I did not find any solutions from gatsby itself, I adjusted my deployment to match the gatsby docs. I now use heroku buildpacks to build my project. While doing so, you can define a file called `static.json`.

This file has options like 

`"https_only": true,
"canonical_host": "yoursite.com"`

With these options, heroku prepares the app to have a redirect from www to non-www and http to https. More information here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-to-heroku/